# Problema ao fazer break no if

Tags: javascript

Se eu colocar um `break` no primeiro laço **`if`**, simplesmente não funciona nem executa nada.. Parece que o `break` é lido antes de tudo, mesmo sem entrar na condição `if`. Qual o problema?

```
function verifynasc(field) {
    var nascimento = field.value;
    alert(nascimento);
    if (nascimento.length > 10) {
        alert("entrou no if");
    }
    nascimento = nascimento.replace('/', '');
    var dia = '';
    var mes = '';
    var ano = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < nascimento.length; i++) {
        if (i < 2) {
            var dia = dia + nascimento.charAt(i);
            continue
        } else if (i < 4) {
            var mes = mes + nascimento.charAt(i);
            continue
        } else {
            var ano = ano + nascimento.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    var data = ano + "-" + mes + "-" + dia;
    document.getElementById('date').value = data;
}
```

Comment: Qual é o problema que tem? pode explicar melhor? (sugestões entretanto: use `nascimento = nascimento.replace('/', '');` em vez desse `replaceAll`, e junte `var` dentro do for para ficar `for (var i = 0;  etc...`)

Comment: Problema é que, eu queria que quando entra-se para condição IF ele de-se o break! só que se eu colocar o break para fazer tal ação, mesmo não entrando na condição IF meu código vai pro saco. todo meu documento que tá contido os códigos javascript não funcionam.. 
replaceAll eu uso para substituir todos e não somente um, foi uma função que criei para isso.

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus Se seu loop começa em `0` e o primeiro `if` testa por `i < 2` então ele **sempre** vai entrar no `if` e ele **sempre** vai sair fora do loop nesse momento! Se você está dizendo que seu código *inteiro* para de funcionar ao colocar o `break`, só pode ser um erro de sintaxe (você não estaria por acaso colocando `break` e `continue` no mesmo `if`, estaria? E a propósito, sempre use `;`, não importa se a linguagem exige ou não). Abra no Chrome por exemplo, e veja no console se ele está acusando erro de sintaxe.

Comment: primeiro if é outro, este que você está apontando é o segundo, antes do próprio laço for.

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus, que valores pode ter a variável `nascimento`?

Answer (score 3):

Seu código poderia ser melhorado, reestruture estes **if**s, para que não precise do *return*, que você pensou ser o *continue*.

O problema é que *break* e *continue* são para LOOPS, não para IF

Ao invés do continue, você usaria **return** no **if**.

O comando **break** "pula fora" de um laço (loop).

O comando **continue** "pula apenas" uma interação do laço (loop).

```
function verifynasc(field) {
    var nascimento = field.value;
    alert(nascimento);
    if (nascimento.length > 10) {
        alert("entrou no if");
    }
    nascimento = nascimento.replace('/', '');
    var dia = '';
    var mes = '';
    var ano = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < nascimento.length; i++) {
        if (i < 2) {
            dia = dia + nascimento.charAt(i);
        } else if (i > 3 && i < 4) {
            mes = mes + nascimento.charAt(i);
        } else {
            ano = ano + nascimento.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    var data = ano + "-" + mes + "-" + dia;
    document.getElementById('date').value = data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que li bem o teu código, estás a tentar garântir que:

- Uma data introduzida com `/` é depois enviada com `-`;
- Uma data no formato "DD-MM-YYYY" é depois enviada em "YYYY-MM-DD".

Algo mais simples poderia ser:

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/tarek9vh/)

#### HTML

```html
<input value="" onblur="formatDate(this)" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/\-/g,'/')">
```

#### JS

```js
function formatDate (field) {
    var date = new Date(field.value);
    var year = date.getFullYear(), month = (date.getMonth() + 1), day = date.getDate();
    if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
    if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;

    field.value = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;   
}
```

A ideia é ter o evento `blur` a chamar a função que vai formatar a data, enquanto temos o evento `keyup` a trocar o `-` por `/` para que a função de formatação funcione corretamente.

Desta forma evitar ciclos e verificações via `IF~ELSE`.